# Where to unregister as observer of NotificationCentre in iOS6?

Tags: ios6, nsnotificationcenter

Before iOS5 most people did it in dealloc. By iOS5 that functionality migrated to viewDidUnload. Now that viewDidUnload is deprecated and never gets called, it would seem we will have to find new spot to unregister our observer.

Question is, where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Apple docs views are never unloaded anymore.

> Prior to iOS 6, when a low-memory warning occured, the
>   UIViewController class purged its views if it knew it could reload or
>   recreate them again later. If this happens, it also calls the
>   viewWillUnload and viewDidUnload methods to give your code a chance to
>   relinquish ownership of any objects that are associated with your view
>   hierarchy, including objects loaded from the nib file, objects created
>   in your viewDidLoad method, and objects created lazily at runtime and
>   added to the view hierarchy. On iOS 6, views are never purged and
>   these methods are never called. If your view controller needs to
>   perform specific tasks when memory is low, it should override the
>   didReceiveMemoryWarning method.

So, you put your unregister command into `-(void)dealloc` or `-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning`. Even in Arc `-(void)dealloc` get's called, you just can't have a call to `[super dealloc]`.